# Passing Data from android to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

What's wrong with my android and php code. whenever I pass a data from android there's no error shown in the android code but in the mysql in php stillthere is  no data that I  receive from android.

here is the code of android.

```
package com.example.datatoserver;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    StringBody tname, tdetails, tcategory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainName);
        TextView details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainDetails);
        TextView category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainCategory);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainSubmit);

        tname = new StringBody(name.getText().toString(),
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        tdetails = new StringBody(details.getText().toString(),
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        tcategory = new StringBody(category.getText().toString(),
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    StringBody[] params = { tname, tdetails, tcategory };
                    new uploadToInternet().execute(params);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("conenction", "connection error: " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}

class uploadToInternet extends AsyncTask<StringBody, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(StringBody... params) {
        try {
            upload(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
            Log.d("success 2", "success");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error", "" + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void upload(StringBody name, StringBody details, StringBody category)
            throws Exception {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.101/android_connect2/create_report.php";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        // post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addPart("name", name);
        builder.addPart("details", details);
        builder.addPart("category", category);

        post.setEntity(builder.build());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String t = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.d("status :", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        Log.d("return :", t);

        entity.consumeContent();
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        Log.d("success", "success");
    }
}
```

here's my php server side code that receives the data from the android

```
 <?php
        $response = array();


        if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['details'])&&isset($_POST['category'])) {


        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $details=$_POST['details'];
        $category=$_POST['category'];

        require_once'db_connect.php';

            $db = new DB_CONNECT();

            $result = ("INSERT INTO reports(name, details, category) VALUES('$name', '$details',                '$category')");
            }
        ?>
```

and here's the DB connection php code

```
 <?php


    class DB_CONNECT{


    function __constructor(){

        $this->connect();
    }
    function __destructor(){


        $this->close();
    }


    function __connect(){

        require_once '/db_config.php';

        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE)or die (mysql_error()) or die (mysql_error());


        return $con;


        }

        function close()
        {

        mysql_close();
            }   

    }

    ?>
```

I really have no Idea why I didn't receive the data into my database. I am sure the php code is correct and so the android? I am hoping for your kind response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: that's where i based my php and but the android part is different. but still no error in android

Comment: You try that tutorial completly u will get it

Comment: can you tell me what's wrong with the code?